# How to sum a "n" number of columns or rows

Tags: php

- Each user must fill each month a number of parameters.
- The number of parameters that need to supplement it varies from user to user, and
  each user can add a new parameter (but they can not delete existing
  ones if they already have values filled in).
  **EX**: **user_1** has: param_1, param_2; **user_2** has: param_1, param_3, param_4, and so.
- I have to sum these parameters at the user level.

I have two problems:

**which is the best option for table structure?**
considering: the max number of parameters a user cah have is 12; the number of active users will reach around 5000 (i hope)

- distinct columns

| user_id | month | param_1 | param_2 | ... | param_12|

- distinct rows:

  | user_id | month    | param_id | param_value |

  | 001     | nov-2012 | param_1  | 100         |

  | 001     | nov-2012 | param_2  | 125         |

  | 002     | nov-2012 | param_1  | 110         |

  | 002     | nov-2012 | param_3  | 150         |

  | 002     | nov-2012 | param_4  | 175         |

and how can I calculate the sum of parameters fosr each user, considering the best option for table structure?

Comment: I think distinct rows is best option, so that you don't have to worry about different users param count ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the second approach is the best suited for your case because in that case you are not wasting any memory and in future if you have to extend your database then also it not need any significant changes to the database.

Now the second problem of summing the parameter then you can fetch all the record of a particular user by its user_id and then add all those values

You can write query as follow's

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(param_value) FROM table_name WHERE param_id = $id"; 
mysql_query($query);
```